# Can't get Python to import a class from file in the same directory

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to import a class from one file to another in the same directory but I can't seem to get python to see the other file that I've written. I'm trying to import the RandomWalk class that I wrote in the random_walk.py file to the rw_visual.py file. However I get the ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. Any help would be appreciated. I get the error in the from random_walk import RandomWalk

random_walk.py:

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk:
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:

            x_direction = choice([1, -1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance

            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue

            # adds the _steps to the current position of the walk
            x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            self.x_values.append(x)
            self.y_values.append(y)
```

rw_visual:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from .random_walk import Randomwalk

rw = Randomwalk()
rw.fill_walk()

plt.style.use('classic')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You need an `_init_.py` (double underscores) file for python to recognize it as a module. Try adding an empty init file.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I added an empty __init__.py to the same the directory as the other two files. Could it be that it is a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, you do need a subdirectory. In one directory, you can have rw_visual, but the random_walk and init files need to be in a directory together.

Comment: I currently have all three in the same directory, should I move the rw_visual into a new directory?

Comment: Yes, along with the init.

Comment: Got it to work, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

add empty `__init__.py` in your directory